# Kotlin: Can you use named arguments for varargs?

Tags: function, kotlin, default-value, variadic-functions, named-parameters

For example, you might have function with a complicated signature and varargs:

```
fun complicated(easy: Boolean = false, hard: Boolean = true, vararg numbers: Int)
```

It would make sense that you should be able to call this function like so:

```
complicated(numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Unfortunately the compiler doesn't allow this.

Is it possible to use named arguments for varargs? Are there any clever workarounds?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It can be worked around by moving optional arguments after the `vararg`:

```
fun complicated(vararg numbers: Int, easy: Boolean = false, hard: Boolean = true) = {}
```

Then it can be called like this:

```
complicated(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
complicated(1, 2, 3, hard = true)
complicated(1, easy = true)
```

Note that trailing optional params need to be always passed with name.
This won't compile:

```
complicated(1, 2, 3, 4, true, true) // compile error
```

Another option is to spare `vararg` sugar for explicit array param:

```
fun complicated(easy: Boolean = false, hard: Boolean = true, numbers: IntArray) = {}

complicated(numbers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: Changing the signature is not nice to users of the function. By tradition vararg is last, and it can lead to problems when you want just call it normally as you pointed out; `numbers = *intArrayOf(...)` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 37):

To pass a named argument to a vararg parameter, use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

```
complicated(numbers = *intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin Docs says clearly that:

> #### Variable number of arguments (Varargs)
>
> A parameter of a function (normally the last one) may be marked with
>   `vararg` modifier:
>
> ```
> fun <T> asList(vararg ts: T): List<T> {
>   val result = ArrayList<T>()
>   for (t in ts) // ts is an Array
>     result.add(t)
>   return result
> }
> ```
>
> allowing a variable number of arguments to be passed to the function:
>
> ```
>   val list = asList(1, 2, 3)
> ```
>
> Inside a function a `vararg`-parameter of type `T` is visible as an
>   array of `T`, i.e. the `ts` variable in the example above has type
>   `Array<out T>`.
>
> Only one parameter may be marked as `vararg`. If a `vararg` parameter
>   is not the last one in the list, values for the following parameters
>   can be passed using the named argument syntax, or, if the parameter
>   has a function type, by passing a lambda outside parentheses.
>
> When we call a `vararg`-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one,
>   e.g. `asList(1, 2, 3)`, or, if we already have an array and want to
>   pass its contents to the function, we use the **spread** operator
>   (prefix the array with `*`):
>
> ```
> val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
> val list = asList(-1, 0, *a, 4)
> ```
>
> From: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

To resume, you can make it using spread operator so it would look like:

```
complicated(numbers = *intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

The vararg parameter can be anywhere in the list of parameters. See example below of how it may be called with different set of parameters. BTW any call can also provide lambda after closed parenthesis.

```
fun varargs(
  first: Double = 0.0,
  second: String = "2nd",
  vararg varargs: Int,
  third: String = "3rd",
  lambda: ()->Unit = {}
) {
  ...
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val list = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)

  varargs(1.0, "...", *list, third="third")
  varargs(1.0, "...", *list)
  varargs(1.0, varargs= *list, third="third")
  varargs(varargs= *list, third="third")
  varargs(varargs= *list, third="third", second="...")
  varargs(varargs= *list, second="...")

  varargs(1.0, "...", 1, 2, 3, third="third")
  varargs(1.0, "...", 1, 2, 3)
  varargs(1.0)

  varargs(1.0, "...", third="third")
  varargs(1.0, third="third")
  varargs(third="third")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function with vararg like this:

```kotlin
complicated(numbers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

The spread (*) operator is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

below is a sample code for adding named argument for a varargs with custom string value

```
<string name="some_text">Some text with  custom value %1$s</string>


Text(
      modifier = modifier.padding(top = 24.dp),
      text = stringResource(
              id = R.string.some_text)
                .format(args = arrayOf("String value")),
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

If the `vararg` argument is positional, with no default value, I found the best way to implement this is to have the first argument be your `vararg` argument. for example:

```kotlin
// define function like so
fun complicated(
    vararg numbers: Int, 
    easy: Boolean = false, 
    hard: Boolean = true
) { /* Do something */}

// then call function like so
complicated(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, easy = true)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the first part of @Vadzim's answer, where they suggest moving the optional arguments after the vararg.