# How to dynamically pass parameters in the Android ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

In the following variables, how do I dynamically pass user.id and friend.id

```kotlin
class WindViewModel @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    val userWindList = Pager(config = pagingConfig, remoteMediator = WindRemoteMediator("userWindList", user.id, friend.id, database!!, api)) {
        windRepository.pagingModelList(friend.id, "userWindList")
    }.flow.map { pagingData ->
        pagingData.map { it.json.toWind() }
    }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Comment: By dynamic, do you mean at the time viewModel is created ( like passing in the constructor) or during runtime?

Comment: @MohammadDerakhshan When running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you specifically mean how to base a Flow on dynamically passed-in values.

I have not used Paging, so I'm not 100% sure this is correct. Specifically, I don't know if is OK to swap to a different Pager source in the same Flow.

But assuming it is OK, one way is to use a MutableSharedFlow as a base for the flow, and use `flatMapLatest` on it. You can dynamically change the parameters that your Flow is based on by emitting to the MutableSharedFlow.

```
data class WindRemoteMediatorParams(val userId: String, val friendId: String) // helper class

private val mediatorParams = MutableSharedFlow<WindRemoteMediatorParams>(replay = 1)

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
val userWindList = mediatorParams.flatMapLatest { (userId, friendId) ->
    Pager(config = pagingConfig, remoteMediator = WindRemoteMediator("userWindList", userId, friendId, database!!, api)) {
        windRepository.pagingModelList(friend.id, "userWindList")
    }.flow
}.map { pagingData ->
    pagingData.map { it.json.toWind() }
}.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

fun beginPaging(userId: String, friendId: String) {
    mediatorParams.tryEmit(WindRemoteMediatorParams(userId, friendId))
}
```

Comment: Use this `val pagingItems = viewModel.userWindList.collectAsLazyPagingItems()`

Comment: A new problem has occurred, and paging cannot be used

Comment: Sorry, I know Flows well but have zero experience with Paging. I suspect maybe it doesn't allow you to swap Pager source mid-flow, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. It's my other fault. It's available now. There's no problem with paging. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass arguments dynamically on a `Kotlin` function is like this:

```
...
val sumOfSomeInts = sumOfSomeInts(1, 3, 7, 2)
...
fun sumOfSomeInts(vararg num: Int): Int {
    var sum = 0
    for(n in num) {
        sum += n
    }
    return sum
} 
...
```

However, I would suggest you leave `vararg` parameters on the front of the parameters list, or at least you use `named arguments` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38941244/9410164)

Comment: If 1,3,7,2 is also dynamic, how to deal with it?